# CSS3 custom Font Face not working well in html view

Tags: html, fonts, css, font-face

Dear folks,
Im trying to figure out what is wrong in here, why the fonts set do not show up correctly in html live view in FireFox 4...  I am clueless! Any insight will be greatly appreciated by me. Any at all! Thanks in advance. Cheers!

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face{
  font-family: "ZZZ";
  src: local('FONT'),
      url('http://www.site.org/FONT.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('http://www.site.org/FONT.eot') format('eot'),
      url('http://www.site.org/FONT.otf') format ('otf'),
      url('http://www.site.org/FONT.woff') format('woff')
}

html, body{font-family: "ZZZ" !important}
```

.

PS.  I changed the name to `"ZZZ"` deliberately into something else than the local file name `"FONT"` so that way I can assure that if someone does NOT have the font locally, it will proceed to download CSS3 url. This however does not work... (when changing ZZZ to Lithos Pro Regular, it works but that is no challenge... I want it to work naturally when no local font file is present.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'do not show up correctly'.

Comment: Please be aware that you are not allowed to use this font in your website.

Comment: Zippy, it dit not work on ANYTHING so this is just an example (actually this is the most comical, unpleasant font you can imagine to put your blog texts into so I was not planning on using it on any meaningful website) I was just bit unhappy why this method as a whole did not work out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent guide here

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

Looks like this could be a version support issue - what version of firefox you using?

Comment: Thanks. Im on FireFox 4 !! so that is not it (unfortunately)

Comment: @sam - no problem worth checking - can you try the code (step 4) on the link I posted then?

Comment: +1 for the excellelllleent link tough as that seems to work WELL!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer only supports `.eot` type fonts and Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support `.ttf` and `.otf` type fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the local font like this instead:

```
html, body{font-family: "LithosProRegular", "ZZZ" !important}
```